# JSX conditional style

Tags: react-native, jsx

I have to set a component left if `isLTR` or right if `isRTL` 
this component is `position: 'absolute',`
so I have to set `right:0` or `left:0` 
this is what I done

```
 isAR === 'rtl'? right: 0,: left: 0,
```

it doesn't work, I can only do this:

```
right:isAR === 'rtl'? 0: 50,
```

what can I do if I wanna work with this logic: `isAR === 'rtl'? right: 0,: left: 0,`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to conditionally apply inline styles:

```
style={ isAR === 'rtl' ? { right: 0 } : { left: 0 } }
```

You can use `classModifier` to add a conditional style.

Comment: yes I know this method but I asked myself if I can do it in other way 
but thank you for the answer